# Reassign values of multidimensional char array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I have an array of strings in C:

```
char taula[15][15];
```

This table is filled with the sentences of a file. The maximum letters a word can have is 15. The maximum words a phrase can have is also 15. This is its content:

```
{ "may", "the", "force", "be", "with", "you." }
```

Now, I need to change the order of the words so they are not in this order (but that doesn't matter for the question).

I am new to C, and what my brain has though is this (this is what I would do in Java):

```
char aux[15] = "";
char frase_nova[15][15];
for(i=0;i<15;i=i+2) {
    aux = taula[i];
    taula[i] = taula[i+1];
    i++;
}
```

I create an aux variable to store a word, and create a new array to store the disordered phrase. I store the 1st element to the aux variable. Assign the 0th element to the 1st, and finally I assign the aux to the 0th element, and so on. This way I should get this phrase as result:

```
the may be force you. with
```

This has caused me an error, so I searched why, and I changed that code to this code, using strcpy:

```
strcpy(aux,frase_nova[i+1]);
strcpy(frase_nova[i+1],frase_nova[i]);
strcpy(frase_nova[i],aux);
printf("%s",frase_nova[i]);
```

But this causes me a strange result. Something that I don't understand is happening with the pointers and the arrays or whatever it is.

```
the E�Ube you.��aE�URE�U
```

So I would like to know how to fill a new multidimensional char array with values of an original multidimensional char array in the order ([i]) I want.

Comment: Strings are arrays.  Arrays can't be copied with a single assignment statement.  Use the string functions in string.h

Comment: @stark The OP seems to be already aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The maximum letters a word can have is 15.*

Then you should have size of words, in 2D `char` array, as `16` and not `15`

```
    char taula[15][16];
                   ^^
```

because, in C, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'`. Hence, you need space to accommodate null character `'\0'`.

Your array has `6` strings i.e. `3` pairs, so you need iterate loop only `3` times. But, looks at this `for` loop:

```
for(i=0;i<15;i=i+2) {
```

it will iterate for more than `3` times. May you can keep track of number of elements in your `2D` array and use it instead of `15` in the loop condition.

As you understood that these statements, of `for` loop body, won't work:

```
    aux = taula[i];
    taula[i] = taula[i+1];
```

because both `aux` and `taula` are arrays. But there is one more problem in your loop body and which is this statement:

```
    i++;
```

You are already incrementing `i` in loop - `i=i+2` and if you do `i++` in loop body then, in every iteration, `i` will be incremented by `3` and which will not give the desired results. You don't need to do `i++` in loop body.

There is no problem with these statements:

```
strcpy(aux,frase_nova[i+1]);
strcpy(frase_nova[i+1],frase_nova[i]);
strcpy(frase_nova[i],aux);
printf("%s",frase_nova[i]);
```

provided

- if the array `frase_nova` has elements `{ "may", "the", "force", "be", "with", "you." }`, and.
- loop variable `i` is incremented twice only in every iteration.

Check the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORDS   15
#define WORD_SZ 16
#define NUM_ELE 6

int main(void) {
    char frase_nova[WORDS][WORD_SZ] = { "may", "the", "force", "be", "with", "you." };
    char aux[WORD_SZ] = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ELE; i = i + 2) {
        // using your posted statements as it is
        strcpy(aux, frase_nova[i + 1]);
        strcpy(frase_nova[i + 1], frase_nova[i]);
        strcpy(frase_nova[i], aux);
        printf("%s ", frase_nova[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    for (int  i = 0; i < NUM_ELE; ++i) {
        printf ("%s ", frase_nova[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
the be you. 
the may be force you. with
```

> *So I would like to know how to fill a new multidimensional char array with values of an original multidimensional char array*

This is not clear whether you want to fill the new multidimensional `char` array with the values of original multidimensional `char` array before swapping the strings of original array or after swapping the strings. But, whatever you want, you can simply achieve it by doing this - `strcpy(frase_nova[i], taula[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

To swap 6 words you need to iterate 6 times, not 15 times. Unless you simply wish to shuffle words around according to some strange pattern.

Also the loop doesn't make any sense. I don't understand why you do `i=i+2`. Also any loop of the nature `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)` can never access item `array[i+1]` in the loop body, because that leads to out of bounds access.

Comment: To be fair they’re iterating 5 times, not 15 times: `i+=2` and `i++`. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Uh yeah that's true. Or well, 7 times. Sigh.